# Unable to get "delete" link to work on an admin panel in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, view

I am new to Ruby On Rails and am currently creating standard CRUD operations for an admin panel I am building manually within the app (no admin gems used).

However, When I call a delete link on my `show.html.erb` page nothing happens (no error screen or any other feedback in the browser). Javascript is fully enabled and I believe I have the correct gems installed.

Could someone please let me know the best way to remedy this? I will link all relevant files below:

**app/views/admin/posts/show.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.body %></p><br>
<%= link_to "delete", [:admin, @post], method: :delete %>
```

**controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end

  def show 
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    post_params = params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :slug)
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to [:admin, @post]
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
  end 
end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/admin.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//

//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**app/views/admin/admin.html.erb**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JonBlog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'admin', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'admin', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Console output when 'delete' clicked.**

```
Started GET "/admin/posts/spiral" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-03 23:43:48 +0100
Processing by Admin::PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"spiral"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "spiral"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/friendly_id-5.2.4/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb:60
  Rendering admin/posts/show.html.erb
  Rendered admin/posts/show.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 12.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  namespace :admin do
    resources :posts
  end

  resources :comments

end
```

Comment: Just curious, when you go back to the index page does it show itself as removed?

Comment: No, the post is still there in the index as well.

Comment: Try putting delete in all caps for the method... `method: :DESTROY`

Comment: Also will you include your routes.rb? I see that the full path for the page is /admin/posts/spiral and I’m curious as to what the spiral is. That could be affecting things. Also notice the output you get in the terminal says “GET” which means it’s not using the correct controller action. I will investigate and get back to you.

Comment: Duh I had a brain fart. Put delete for the method.

Comment: Have tried 'DELETE' still no joy, have added routes.rb. 'spiral' is the page id for the post which uses the 'friendly_id' gem.

Comment: Try this: <%= link_to “Delete”, admin_post_path(post), method: :delete %>. HOWEVER, double check what the name of the path is. Go to localhost:3000/rails/info/routes or run `rake routes` to see what the route is for the delete. I think it has something to do with namespacing. If I had my computer with me I’d have had this tested and correct but I’m on mobile, sorry!!

Comment: Also I did look at friendly_id and although this seems like a good idea, this isn’t the most practical solution for ID’s, and it increases predictability. If you don’t use a gem for authentication, you’re opening up the door for people to find files via a naming convention as opposed to an arbitrary numerical ID system. May I ask why you’re doing it that way? Just curious :) EDIT: I realize the uses and that’s pretty cool, just exercise caution on what all you choose to name and being careful to add authentication to the pages you wanna protect.

Comment: Have tried as suggested, unfortunately still no joy :(

Comment: At this point I would re-read the documentation on friendly_id to see if there’s something extra that you’re missing about grabbing the ID, but I can tell you that the actual link code is correct, so I’m stumped. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the route getting hit is a `GET` request, and you are hitting the `show` action. If you inspect the HTML of the page I'll bet it says nothing about the delete method. So the `link_to` call as written must not be passing `:method` correctly.

I'm a little out of practice, but what happens if you try something like `link_to("Delete", admin_post_path(@post), method: :delete)` (that is, using a string url instead of array for domain/resource specifier)?

Comment: the HTML of the link reads as follows `<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/admin/posts/restless">delete</a>`. Will try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: I tried altering the link as suggested. Again nothing changes! The console output is as follows:

Comment: ```Started GET "/admin/posts/spiral" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-04 12:02:32 +0100
Processing by Admin::PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"spiral"}
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "spiral"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/friendly_id-5.2.4/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb:60
  Rendering admin/posts/show.html.erb
  Rendered admin/posts/show.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 12.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)```